Enabling pass through in a Huawei optic router
I have an optic cable that is plugged into the internet providers provided router, Huawei EchoLife HG8145V5.
I also have my own TP-Link AC2300 v2, which has more ports and nicer features.
I currently have the TP-Link plugged into the LAN of the Huawei (thus creating two LAN networks), but I would like to make the Huawei pass through, i.e. it shouldnt have do any NAT translation, it shouldnt have wifi, etc, it should just forward all requests to the TP-Link router.
I cannot find any mention of passthrough or bridge mode in the Huawei router.
Would disabling the DHCP server be enough to make it pass through?
Or are there some other configuration settings I need to change?
Is it even possible to make this router pass through?

Have you tried asking your ISP specifically (or some people who have dealt with the same ISP)? It's not uncommon for ISPs to customize router firmware to hide some options.

Yeah, the router firmware could have the feature removed, didnt think of that.
I just sent the email asking the question to the provider, they usually get back within a day or two.
A general answer to this question regarding what are all the options that must be enabled for a router to work in a true pass through mode still would be good.

Generally fiber optic connections use either plain fiber-Ethernet or more commonly GPON (which still carries Ethernet data), and Ethernet-to-Ethernet passthrough is usually called bridge mode. It completely bypasses the 'IP routing' part of the router, and as far as I know should be present in any GPON device – unless the device has ISP-customized firmware with that option hidden.
(In contrast LTE/4G/5G don't carry Ethernet-like packets at all, only raw IP, so they are not bridgeable; routers with a LTE modem instead call it "passthrough" mode because it is still IP routing, only in a slightly different configuration.)
Disabling DHCP will not switch the device to bridge mode. The commonly given advice to disable DHCP would only apply if you wanted to make use of the pre-existing LAN-only bridge that home gateways generally have across their LAN+WiFi interfaces – but it won't add the WAN port to said bridge.
If the ISP allows, it might be possible to connect your own GPON ONT(ONU) instead of the Huawei. (Our largest ISP doesn't provide combo routers; they instead provide small Huawei or ZTE ONTs that just convert GPON to regular Ethernet for the router.)

@grawity suggested I contact my ISP with questions regarding the hardware they provide which is the best approach in this case, shame I didnt think of it before posting the question.
The answer, which is specific for this hardware and maybe even this ISP, is that there is no way to change the router to work in bridged mode, but there is a LAN port (port #4) that is dedicated to bridging.
I plugged in my Archer router into port #4 of the Huawei router (I had previously plugged it into port #1, as one does), and I can see the public IP address in the configuration screen of the Archer router.
